# How do you modify date time picker on another form when a datagridview cell is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I am trying to create a form that opens when I click a row within a dataGridView. This contains a start date and an end date. When the new form opens, I want to populate two dateTimePicker`s (dateTimePickerStartDate and dateTimePickerEndDate) with the values in the datagridview.

I have a method for when I click a cell:

```
private void dataGridViewActivityHire_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        DataGridViewRow view = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Form2 newForm = new Form2 ();
        newForm.dateTimePickerStartDate.Value = (DateTime)view.Cells[4].Value;
        newForm.dateTimePickerEndDate.Value = (DateTime)view.Cells[5].Value;
        edit.Show();
    }
}
```

This throws an error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

I tried a different method where I declare DateTime variables in form2, but I couldn't get this working:

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

and I set the values oof the dateTimePickers:

```
    dateTimePickerStartDate.Value = StartDate;
    dateTimePickerEndDate.Value = EndDate;
```

How might I populate the dateTimePicker's on the other form when the row is clicked?

Comment: What is the values of the grid cells? `view.Cells[4].Value`

Comment: the value is meant to be a datetime string

Comment: I have a datetimepicker that inserts the value into the datagridview from the same form, but want to export the value in the datagridview to a datetimepicker in another form

Comment: it says I cannot convert string to long

Answer (score 0):

The date in the grid cell is a `string`. And assuming the string value is a valid date, then you need to convert that `string` to a `DateTime` object to set the `DateTimePicker` in the second form.

One way to do this is to use the `DateTime.TryParse` method. Example, if the `string`s in cells four (4) and five (5) are valid date time strings, then you could parse those to a `DateTime` object like…

```
DataGridViewRow view = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Form2 newForm = new Form2();
if (DateTime.TryParse(view.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out DateTime startDate)) {
  newForm.dateTimePickerStartDate.Value = startDate;
}
else {
  // date-time string is not a valid date time string 
}

if (DateTime.TryParse(view.Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out DateTime endDate)) {
  newForm.dateTimePickerEndDate.Value = endDate;
}
else {
  // date-time string is not a valid date time string 
}
newForm.Show();
```